# The name 'PropertySupport' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reflection, inotifypropertychanged

I would like to create a base class for observableObject generic enough for an observable object to derive from, but I hit some technical issue. This is an extract of the class. It is an abstract that implements interface INotifyPropertyChanged. But when I tried to use PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName, I got compiler error saying 'PropertySupport' not exist in the current context. I am using VS2002. My intention was to create a library to host a small "framework" of my own and use it for different projects. Could anyone more well versed in the reflection point out what was wrong in my code to cause the compiler error?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    namespace MyFramework
    {
        [Serializable]
        public abstract class ObservableObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            [field: NonSerialized]
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler!=null)
                {
                    handler(this, e);
                }
            }

            protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
            {
                var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpression);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }
            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you missing a using directive or referenced dll?

Comment: @Kerry: I do not think so, I think I may have more directive than I need. Anyhow, I edited my question to include the whole module for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting usually refers to a missing using directive or missing reference.

Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406219%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for the function you are trying to use it looks like you are missing the using directive Prism.ViewModel

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then you need to add a reference to the correct dll

```
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll
```

I've never used [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) but after copying your class, adding the correct reference & using directive it built ok.

Comment: Sounds like it. And also, it looks like PropertySupport is obsolete. But where do you get the dll? I can not see it anywhere, were you getting it from NuGet or have you downloaded it from Microsoft site?

Comment: @user1205746 I downloaded it from [here](http://microsoft.com/us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42537), it unzipped a sample solution which then used nuget.